# Why do FPGAs use LUTs rather than traditional logic gates?

Tags: architecture, fpga, lookup-tables

Why do FPGA chips implement their logic using lookup tables? I've read that lookup tables are more efficient than actually performing the computations, but if that's the case why don't all chips use LUTs? What makes LUTs specifically advantageous for FPGAs?

Answer (score 3):

It's about the balance between functionality and costs.

The LUT can implement any function of its inputs, and it's reloadable. Traditional logic gates can do only one job for which it was built.

FPGA must be able to freely reconfigure its cells, and you want all the flexibility you can get. And LUT is the way to have it.

On the other hand, if your device has fixed functionality, then you can save the costs and power by dropping big redundant LUT, and implement in silicon only required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It is already in the name: Field ***Programmable*** Gate Array.

You can't program gates as they form a static function. The most efficient way of making "programmable" gates has been the Look-Up-Table.

What is often forgotten is that you also need a **programmable** interconnect structure to connect the LUTs (and the registers) in different ways. That also uses a significant part of the FPGA silicon area. With pure logic, you can just use wires and buffers.